# How to maximize all windows from command line

Tags: command-line, window-manager, wmctrl

To maximise all windows from the command line, it would be great if `wmctrl` could be used as easily in minimizing all windows.
How do I can use it to do the reverse?

Answer (score 2):

... the right answer for "command (line) minimize all" action is that of

`wmctrl -k on`;

sadly to say it, there isn't the equivalent "countermesure" for `wmctrl` to maximize all *simply*, but it can be used in a bash script as [suggested here](https://gist.github.com/platan/e63b465c2fcfe3d0cccd#file-maximize_all-sh).
The code is

```
#!/bin/bash
# create a list of all open windows by ID
window_ids=$(wmctrl -l | cut -f1 -d " ")
# process every window by ID
for window_id in $window_ids
do
    wmctrl -i -r "$window_id" -b add,fullscreen
done
exit 0
```

Don't forget to save your file under whatever name you want, and **make it eXecutable**:

```
chmod +x [myfile_bash]
```

Then you can also assign its link to a keyboard shortcut ;-)

I hope I've been helpful.